# How to fix error when plotting TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable

Tags: geopandas, plot

I am following a Genetic Algorithm for optimizing a bus route network in github https://github.com/Schmidtbit/Bus-Route-Optimization. I have finished cleaning up most of the errors and getting the algorithm to work but I am stuck with an error for the function for plotting the network.

```
def plot(self):
    '''
    OUTPUT: plot of routes
    '''

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
    for n in range(self.N):
        # Make LineString Objects
        route_a_line = self.route_line(self.route_list[n][1])
        route_b_line = self.route_line(self.route_list[n][2])

        # Make Geo DataFrames
        route_a_geo = self.transform_to_GeoDataFrame(route_a_line)
        route_b_geo = self.transform_to_GeoDataFrame(route_b_line)

        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,n+1)
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        
        print(self.roads)
        
        self.roads.plot(ax=ax,color='black', linewidth=.5 )
        self.region.plot(ax=ax, color='orange', alpha=.2)
        self.bus_stops_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='red',markersize=8)

        route_a_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='green', linewidth=1)
        route_b_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='blue', linewidth=1)

        ax.set_title('East Side Route Map {}\nFitness = {}'.format(n+1,self.route_list[n][0]))
        ax.set_ylim((self.miny, self.maxy))
        ax.set_xlim((self.minx, self.maxx))
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
    plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
           LINEARID              FULLNAME RTTYP  MTFCC  \
40     110485879145          Redondo Dr N     M  S1400   
103    110485879146          Redondo Dr S     M  S1400   
145    110485713388              5th St E     M  S1400   
146    110485714851             32nd St E     M  S1400   
157    110485714336             11th St E     M  S1400   
...             ...                   ...   ...    ...   
19248  110485877978         S L Davis Ave     M  S1400   
19374  110485887172        N I- 35 Svc Rd     M  S1400   
19393  110485901473   N Interregional Hwy     M  S1400   
19416  110485905152  N Pleasant Valley Rd     M  S1400   
19553  110485888529    Old E Riverside Dr     M  S1400   

                                                geometry  in_boundary  \
40     LINESTRING (-97.68178 30.28154, -97.68239 30.2...         True   
103    LINESTRING (-97.68271 30.28083, -97.68212 30.2...         True   
145    LINESTRING (-97.69771 30.25189, -97.69632 30.2...         True   
146    LINESTRING (-97.72316 30.28912, -97.72312 30.2...         True   
157    LINESTRING (-97.73329 30.27056, -97.73312 30.2...         True   
...                                                  ...          ...   
19248  LINESTRING (-97.71925 30.27073, -97.71828 30.2...         True   
19374  LINESTRING (-97.73050 30.27595, -97.73046 30.2...         True   
19393  LINESTRING (-97.73050 30.27595, -97.73046 30.2...         True   
19416  LINESTRING (-97.71351 30.25043, -97.71343 30.2...         True   
19553  LINESTRING (-97.73230 30.24584, -97.73143 30.2...         True   

         length  
40     0.001239  
103    0.001830  
145    0.001515  
146    0.000120  
157    0.000849  
...         ...  
19248  0.003948  
19374  0.000122  
19393  0.000122  
19416  0.027898  
19553  0.001262  

[662 rows x 7 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18244\690027505.py in <module>
----> 1 model.plot()

~\Downloads\Bus-Route-Optimization-master\RouteFinder1.0\RouteFinder.py in plot(self)
    288             print(self.roads)
    289 
--> 290             self.roads.plot(ax=ax,color='black', linewidth=.5 )
    291             self.region.plot(ax=ax, color='orange', alpha=.2)
    292             self.bus_stops_geo.plot(ax=ax, color='red',markersize=8)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
--> 606         return plot_dataframe(self, *args, **kwargs)
    607 
    608     plot.__doc__ = plot_dataframe.__doc__

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in plot_dataframe(df, column, cmap, color, ax, cax, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, markersize, figsize, legend_kwds, classification_kwds, **style_kwds)
    493 
    494     if column is None:
--> 495         return plot_series(
    496             df.geometry,
    497             cmap=cmap,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in plot_series(s, cmap, color, ax, figsize, **style_kwds)
    346     if not lines.empty:
    347         values_ = values[line_idx] if cmap else None
--> 348         plot_linestring_collection(
    349             ax, lines, values_, color=color, cmap=cmap, **style_kwds
    350         )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in plot_linestring_collection(ax, geoms, values, color, cmap, vmin, vmax, **kwargs)
    154     from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
    155 
--> 156     geoms, multiindex = _flatten_multi_geoms(geoms, range(len(geoms)))
    157     if values is not None:
    158         values = np.take(values, multiindex)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in _flatten_multi_geoms(geoms, colors)
     36     for geom, color in zip(geoms, colors):
     37         if geom.type.startswith("Multi"):
---> 38             for poly in geom:
     39                 components.append(poly)
     40                 # repeat same color for all components

TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please include the full exception traceback in the body of your question.